# How to isolate conversion of Strings to different Classes in Java?

Tags: java, string, generics

I have an initial set of data that can come in two different formats that need to be matched against. The entries will be either an exact match or provide a range. The range values will be integers in decimal format - but the data to match could be hex as well as decimal. The base will be indicated within the initial data. So the initial data will look something like the following (JSON formatted):

```
[ 
    {"value":"X"}, 
    {"value":"Y"}, 
    {"START":"0000", "END":"0010", "INPUTBASE":"10"},
    {"START":"0200", "END":"0300", "INPUTBASE":"16"}
]
```

So I need a function something like `boolean contains(final String value)` that would check to see if value is contained in the "keeper" set The strings X, Y, 8, FF would all hit - FF as a hex number (multiple matches are not a concern). What I have done is create two sets one with single values and one with [Range](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html)s wrapped to include the base. My code is something like the following:

```
Set<WrappedRange> wrappedRangeSet;
Set<String> singleEntrySet;
public boolean contains(final String value) {
    return singleEntrySet.contains(value) || valueInRange(value);
}

private boolean valueInRange(final String incoming) {
    Long value;
    for(WrappedRange<Long> wrappedRange : wrappedRangeSet) {
        try {
            value = Long.valueOf(incoming, wrappedRange.getBase());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            continue; // not worried if wrong format...
        }
        if (wrappedRange.contains(value)) {
            return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
}
```

The WrappedRange looks like:

```
class WrappedRange<C Extends Comparable> {
    private final int base;
    private final Range<C> range;

    public WrappedRange(final Range<C> range, final int base) {
        this.range = range;
        this.base = base;
    }

    public boolean contains(final C value) {
         return range.contains(value);
    }

    public int getBase() {
         return int base;
    }
}
```

At the minimum I would like to get rid of the `WrappedRange.getBase()` method and move the conversion from String to the desired type into the WrappedRange class. Then a `contains(String)` method could be added to `WrappedRange` class. The loop in the `valueInRange` method be reduced to:

```
for(WrappedRange<Long> wrappedRange : wrappedRangeSet) {
    if (wrappedRange.contains(value)) {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

The problem I'm running into is that I've made the assumption the value I am comparing is a Long, and not *any* extension of Comparable. I could just fix the WrappedRange to use Longs, but then I can't use the class for other Comparables.

Ideally I'd like to restrict the conversion of the Strings to the WrappedRange class, as there is the possibility other extensions of Comparable may be used for input to the contains function in the future. The class would look something like the following:

```
class WrappedRange<C Extends Comparable> {
    private final int base;
    private final Range<C> range;

    public WrappedRange(final Range<C> range, final int base) {
        this.range = range;
        this.base = base;
    }

    public boolean contains(final C value) {
         return range.contains(value);
     }

    public boolean contains(final String incoming) {
         C value = convert(incoming);
         return range.contains(value);
     }

    private convert(final String incoming) {
         // ... convert to type C and return.
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried Deserializing the Json into Java objects, and then validating/comparing specific values?

Comment: The initial set in JSON formatted which is deserialized to fill the sets, but the data received later to chack if it exists in the sets will be straight Strings. So I'm not clear on how this might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input will always be a string, and the internal structure will always be a range, why not do something like this?

```
public abstract class WrappedRange<C extends Comparable> {
  private final Range<C> range;

  protected WrappedRange(Range<C> range) {
    this.range = range;
  }

  public boolean contains(String incoming) {
    try {
      C value = convert(incoming);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return false;
    }
    return range.contains(value);
  }

  protected abstract C convert(String incoming);
}

class WrappedLongRange extends WrappedRange<Long> {
  private final int base;

  WrappedLongRange(Range<Long> range, int base) {
    super(range);
    this.base = base;
  }

  @Override
  protected Long convert(String incoming) {
    return Long.valueOf(incoming, base);
  }
}
```